# Table join only inserting values depending on values in column from other table

Tags: postgresql, attribute-joins

I have two tables. One table with areas of certain types `a.matrikulaere_foreninger` with 274 rows and another table with a column called `b.pnr`.

I want to create a view where the `pnr` from table `b` is joined to table `a`, but I only want the `pnr` to be joined when `a.type_mg` is different from the value 'Almen boligforening'.

I have tried the following.

```
SELECT a.gid,
a.type_mg,
a.cvrnr,
a.the_geom,
CASE WHEN type_mg <> 'Almen boligforening' 
    THEN b.pnr 
    ELSE NULL 
    END pnr
FROM _01_fysisk_plan_og_naturbeskyt.matrikulaere_foreninger a
    LEFT JOIN _00_grundkort.cvr_prod_enhkomgeoview b ON a.cvrnr = b.virksomhed_cvrnr;
```

The above query results i a new table with 311 rows because there are multiple `pnr` for every `type_mg` = 'Almen boligforening'. But I want to end up with a view with 274 rows with `pnr` values for each row with `type_mg`different from 'Almen boligforening' and `NULL` values for columns with `type_mg` = 'Almen boligforening'.

Comment: You need to move the condition to the join: `select a.id, ..., b.bnr from .. a left join .. b on a.id=b.id AND a.type_mg != 'almen';`)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!